# Display Multiple InnerJoin in View CakePHP 3.X

Tags: php, cakephp, join, dropdown

How I display a result of a query in a DropDown.

The problem is this:

When I get the result.

This result is an array.

```
foreach ($resultQuery as $row) {
     debug($row);
    }
```

Debug result some like this: 'VOL_ID' => (int) 1, 'VOL_ID' => (int) 2

```
$volunteer=$this->Volunteer->find('list')->where(['VOL_ID' => RESULT QUERY]);
```

The result of a query not displayed in a dropdown.

How can I display all tuples?

---

ANSWER:

```
$query=$this->Volunteer->find('list') ->select(['VOL_NAME'])->where(['VOLUNTEER_ID IN' => $resultQuery]);
```

IN clause compare ID with an array.
Thanks!

Comment: but did the query builder get the correct result?

Comment: @NewbeeDev Yes, the query result is this:
'VOL_ID' => (int) 1,
'VOL_ID' => (int) 2.
(in array)

Comment: can I see your code in dropdown

Comment: @NewbeeDev I got the answer, I edit the post. Thanks!